# Spark streaming source

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

Is it possible to use hive tables as source/sink for spark structured streaming?
Nowhere in the documentation I could see the source or sink as hive tables .
.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

Comment: This is for batch processing , I am more concerned for streaming side

Comment: You can use foreachBatch as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) to make use of batch sources within structured streaming.